# Create Application shortcut with parameters in macOS

Tags: macos, firefox, waterfox

How can I create a new shortcut or edit an existing shortcut on macOS with, for example Waterfox / Firefox?

Here are two examples of parameters I want to use that are from shortcuts on my Windows desktop:

```
"C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\Waterfox\56.0 x64\waterfox.exe" -ProfileManager -no-remote

"C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\Waterfox\56.0 x64\waterfox.exe" -P "Waterfox 56.0"
```

I'd like to be able to edit *existing* shortcuts if possible.

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to establish if those arguments are accepted on the Mac version.

Then you have to use a combination of Applescript & shellscript. Macs have no 'shortcut' structure like Windows does.

Launch Script Editor [in Applications/Utilities] & make a new script*

```
do shell script "\"/Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/Waterfox\" -ProfileManager -no-remote"
quit
```

Save as an Application. Double-click to execute. You may have to tell Gatekeeper to allow it. The app will launch itself, launch Waterfox, then quit itself. You'll probably barely see it happen.

Repeat the process for your other version.
Depending on how Waterfox itself is structured, by this method it may actually be possible to run both of these simultaneously.

Because of the Mac app structure you will probably not need any versioning [56.0 etc], it will automatically launch the current version. Versioning would only be required if the version number is actually a part of the app name itself, which it usually isn't.

*I'm guessing at the precise naming of Waterfox, I don't have it to test.
The first name, 'Waterfox' should be exactly as it is named in the Applications folder, plus '.app'. The second name ought to be simply 'Waterfox' but you can test by right clicking the app itself, select Show Package Contents, then look inside the Contents/MacOS/ folder for the executable name [which won't have any extension]
I had a look at Firefox - that would work exactly as written [subbing 'fire' for 'water' of course.]

You ***could*** do this by modifying the .plist file inside the app itself, but this can lead to issues with Gatekeeper & you also cannot do **both** this way, you'd have to choose one or the other, so I'm not offering that as a viable alternative.